# setting up cadvisor through API

Tags: docker, cadvisor

I am using ubuntu server hosted on cloud and try to setup cadvisor by this command

```
docker run -d --name=cadvisor -p 8080:8080 --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw --volume=/sys:/sys:ro --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro google/cadvisor:latest
```

It gets installed properly, but now I need to expose the API from browser. How do I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to cAdisor Remote REST API by following this:

Example: http://`<host-ip>`:8080/api/v1.3/`<req-path>`.

Refer these docs for further details:

- https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/api.md
- https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/api_v2.md